# How to concatenate Distinct values of a single Column in one row?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with single column Countries as:

```
Countries

USA
USA
France
India
USA
Russia
France
India
```

I want to concatenate distinct values in a single row like

```
Countries

USA,France,India,Russia
```

How do I write SQL query to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH CTE(COUNTRY)AS
(
  SELECT 'USA' UNION ALL
  SELECT'USA'UNION ALL
  SELECT'France'UNION ALL
  SELECT'India'UNION ALL
  SELECT'USA'UNION ALL
  SELECT'Russia'UNION ALL
  SELECT'France'UNION ALL
  SELECT'India'
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(C.COUNTRY,',')
FROM 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY FROM CTE
)C
```

Answer (score 0):

If its from a table Country and fieldName is CountryName, then below query would do good, `SELECT STRING_AGG(CountryName) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CountryName FROM Country)`. Incase if you are using older version of SQL, STUFF can be used to achieve the output.